# Redirect traffic destined for IP and port

Tags: iptables, nat

I have a program that wants to connect to 1.2.3.4 on port 5678, but it can't because the port is blocked on our network. However, I do have an SSH tunnel set up that redirects localhost:5678 to 1.2.3.4:5678.

How do I redirect all traffic to/from 1.2.3.4:5678 so that it actually goes through localhost:5678?

I don't want *all* traffic to/from a specific port to be redirected, nor do I want *all* traffic to/from 1.2.3.4 to go to localhost, just this specific port and IP combination.

Answer (score 0):

I think balance http://www.inlab.de/balance.html 
is a good option for your use case

Though its main purpose is a balancing, it can be used for just traffic
redirection on specific port

balance SOMEPORT anotherhost:SOMEOTHERPORT

will forward all connection to SOMEPORT to  anotherhost:SOMEOTHERPORT